# how to pass parameters to modal popup?

Tags: javascript, nativescript, telerik-appbuilder, modalpopup

I am working on `Nativescript` application where i need to open view on click of list item. So i will have to pass `id` of that item to the modal that is about to open on click of list item.

Here is my code as i tried and for opening modal popup :

```
var modalPageModule = views.appointmentDetails;
var context = {
  id: args.view.bookingId // i tried this way for passing parameter
};
var fullscreen = true;
page.showModal(modalPageModule, context, function closeCallback(parameters) {
 // Log the user in...

}, fullscreen);
```

And code for getting passed parameter on controller of modal popup

```
page = args.object;
var gotData = page.navigationContext;
var id = gotData.id;
```

But returns `NaN`.

Please suggest some way to pass variable to modal popup.

Comment: Please show your 'showModal' function declaration.

Comment: There is no custom methods for showing modal, You can find method i have used here : https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/navigation#modal-pages

Comment: Try to add this `console.log(context)` into showModal function. What result do you get in console?

Comment: I can add that but i think that is `closeCallback` so it will be called on close of popup, not opening.

Comment: on `closeCallback` function it returns correct `{"id":1}`

Comment: @ArmenAvetisyan Found way to pass parameter. Check my answer. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved after making change in XML file

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd"
      xmlns:widgets="utils/widgets"
      showingModally="onLoaded">
```

and in modal controller

```
exports.onLoaded = function(args) {
    var id = args.context.id
```